# python2.7 django 1.10.3. Can't use oauth2app

Tags: python, django

I have installed `oauth2app` using pip and I added it to setting.py, when I run migrate the tables for oauth2app are not created in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

The last update of oauth2app on git was in 2014. So as i understand it didn't support new versions of django. However I [found](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit) `django-oauth-toolkit`, that connect oauth2app with new version of Django. Try it, maybe it's helps you.